# DataView.Count() returns more than one value

Tags: c#, database, winforms, visual-studio-2013, dataview

I'm kinda new to all this so I'll try to be as specific as possible..
I'm trying to create a button that'll display two dates in another form. So I've written this:

```
DataView dv = new DataView(dataComercioDataSet.Comex);
dv.Sort = "Id";
int ixe = dv.Find(idTextBox.Text);
DateTime embarque = Convert.ToDateTime(dv[ixe]["FechaEmbarque"]);
otherForm.fechaEmbarqueDateTimePicker.Value = embarque;
DateTime vencimiento = Convert.ToDateTime(dv[ixe]["FechaVencimiento"]);
otherForm.fechaVencimientoDateTimePicker.Value = vencimiento;
otherForm.idBox1.Text = dv[ixe]["Id"].ToString();
this.comexTableAdapter.FillBy3(this.dataComercioDataSet.Comex, c41TextBox.Text);
```

Now, when I click the button it catches an exception showing that it's a DBNull object. So I decide to test it by adding this:

```
if (dv.Count == 1)
{
    MessageBox.Show("1");
}
if (dv.Count == 0) ;
{
    MessageBox.Show("0");
}
```

And it shows both! Since the exception states that it's DBNull I reckon dv.find must be returning 0, so I figure this:

```
if (ixe == 0)
{
    ixe = 1;
    DateTime embarque = Convert.ToDateTime(dv[ixe]["FechaEmbarque"]);
    otherForm.fechaEmbarqueDateTimePicker.Value = embarque;
    DateTime vencimiento = Convert.ToDateTime(dv[ixe]["FechaVencimiento"]);
    otherForm.fechaVencimientoDateTimePicker.Value = vencimiento;
    otherForm.idBox1.Text = dv[ixe]["Id"].ToString();

    this.comexTableAdapter.FillBy3(this.dataComercioDataSet.Comex, c41TextBox.Text);
}
```

But when I do this, the exception is that index 1 is either negative or superior than row count (it's in spanish, I don't know if that's the actual translation)
Anyway, I think i'm not quite getting how DataView.Find() actually indexes the result, i mean, is row 1 = 1 or 0 ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you'll find that in C#, collections are 0-indexed, meaning that the 1st item is index 0.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to work around this issue, somehow changing

```
DataView dv = new DataView(dataComercioDataSet.Comex);
```

to

```
 DataView dv = new DataView();
          dv = dataComercioDataSet.Comex.AsDataView();
```

solved the problem, not sure why though...